# How to goto/access home directory using python subprocess.run()

Tags: python, subprocess

While using python3 `subprocess.run()`, I need to got/access my home directory. I tried the below commands but their syntax is incorrect. Please advice me on the correct syntax that I should use. Thank you.

**Test Script:**

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.run(['cd', '$HOME'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
sp.run(['cd', '${HOME}'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
sp.run(['cd', '~'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

Comment: what do you plan to do after that ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee `cd` is just a test cmd. In reality, I need to run some program in bash that references the home directory. I am trying to get the referencing syntax for home dir correct. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.environ`:

```
home = os.environ['HOME']
import subprocess as sp
sp.run(['bash', 'cd', home], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

This will not change your python interpreter working directory, for that purpose you might want to use:

```
home = os.environ['HOME']
os.chdir(home)
```

If you need to access subdirectories you can get the paths using `os.path.join`:

```
home = os.environ['HOME']
subdir = 'Documents'  # or get the list of subdirs with os.listdir(home)
subdir_path = os.path.join(home, subdir)
```

Comment: Must I declare `home = os.environ['HOME']` in each python class or at each python module?

Comment: you can use directly `os.environ['HOME']` e.g. `os.chdir(os.environ['HOME'])`

Comment: I got this error msg: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd': 'cd'`. How to fix this? I am using python 3.6.

Comment: Thanks. How do I access/reference the children directories of `home`? E.g. `home/Document` or `~/Document`. I could not get it to work.

Comment: Pardon me. After implementing your latest edit, I ran  `sp.run(['bash', 'cd', subdir_path], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)`. However, I got an error. `CompletedProcess(args=['bash', 'cd', '~/Documents'], returncode=127, stdout=b'', stderr=b'bash: cd: No such file or directory\n')`. The directory does exist. Can you pls advise me again?

Comment: you shouldn't use `~`, because that's a bash shortcut. You should use `os.path.join(os.path.environ['HOME'], 'Documents')`.

Please select this answer as accepted, since it answers your original question. Now if you have further problems, please post a new question with the full code, so that you can get help, instead of posting questions in the comments about errors you get, without showing the code that generated them, because we cannot help properly without the code... Thanks

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I did not use `~`. However, I changed the `/home/user/` syntax to  `~` in my comment. So I had ran `os.path.join(os.path.environ['HOME'], 'Documents')` but it returned `stderr=b'bash: cd: No such file or directory\n`.

Comment: Can you add the full code, together with the output of `os.listdir(os.environ['HOME'])`?

Answer (score 0):

@SunBear Try adding `shell=True`. It was not working earlier for you because subprocess can't find the test-cmd cd.

To understand more about `shell=True` you can go here [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)